# How do I bring back the black box when in camera mode

Tags: rendering

I was watching a YouTube video of how to use the camera in blender 2.9. It then said something about the black box showing you hoe your rendered image would look. I tried it out then noticed I didnt have the box. Please help me bring it back.

Comment: FYI the black box is called a [passepartout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_(picture_framing)) in blender :)

Answer (score 0):

Just press the camera icon, which toggles the look through the camera and the "normal" 3D View.

You can also use <kbd>0</kbd> (Zero) on the Numpad to show the camera view.

[image]

Comment: You can also use 0 (zero) on the numpad to show the camera view.

Comment: @JohnEason: Thanks, added this to my answer